# fixing the touchpad scroll speed in ubuntu 18.04 - libinput

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, scrolling, libinput

I know this has has been beaten to death but I still couldn't get it to work based on the solutions I've seen for similar questions. It's always a mouse using libinput or a touchpad using synaptics or something, could not find an answer that worked for me.

I just want to turn down the sensitivity of the scrolling when using the touchpad on my machine.

Using a Dell Latitude E5570 on ubuntu 18.04, with libinput.

```
xinput list
```

gives me

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad          id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick             id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ DELL Wireless hotkeys                     id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

and

```
xinput list-props 13
```

gives me

```
Device 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (169):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (171): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (304): 1
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (305): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (306):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (307):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (308):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (309):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (310):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (311):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (312):   1
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (313):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (314):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (315):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (316):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (317):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (318):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (319):    1
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (320):    1
    libinput Accel Speed (321): 0.397059
    libinput Accel Speed Default (322): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (323): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (324): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (289): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (290):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (291):    0, 0
    Device Node (292):  "/dev/input/event6"
    Device Product ID (293):    2, 8
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (325):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (326):   1
```

any ideas how I could do this? Thanks in advance to those who are much more clever than me

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention it, but I assume you are referring to the sensitivity issue when using Wayland. [u/timrichardson](https://old.reddit.com/user/timrichardson) on [r/gnome](https://old.reddit.com/r/gnome) has [a solution that worked for me](https://old.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/kopjm0/still_no_way_to_adjust_touchpad_scrollspeed/gi0790a/).

To quote:

> Measure your trackpad dimensions. Mine were 100mmx70mm (WxH),
> then halve the dimensions, and do this as root:

```sh
sudo libinput measure touchpad-size 50x35
```

> Make a new file (as root): `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/61-evdev-local.hwdb`
> and paste into it the snippet from the measure touchpad-size command.
> Save, then:

```sh
sudo systemd-hwdb update
sudo udevadm trigger /dev/input/event*
reboot
```

More details can be found here:
https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/absolute-coordinate-ranges.html#absolute-coordinate-ranges-fix