# Slow down two finger scrolling

Tags: touchpad, laptop, 21.10, scrolling

I just switched from windows to Ubuntu last night and I am enjoying everything so far. My biggest issue is that the two finger scrolling speed is super fast for some reason, and at the end of each scroll, the screen "bounces" a little bit. I can't seem to find a way to slow down the scrolling speed.

Comment: It's useful if we can know which flavor you installed. One of the easiest ways is to open your system settings app, and see the contents of the tab "System Informations". You may see "Ubuntu", "Kubuntu", "Xubuntu", "Ubuntu Mate" or something similar. Give us that string. Also, providing your laptop's model and/or trackpad's model may help.

Comment: @Emoji I clicked on the about tab and it says I have Ubuntu 21.10 :,)

Comment: @PabloBianchi I did, but it doesn't fix the two finger scrolling speed problem :( It only makes my cursor move faster!

Comment: This was also on 18.04, you could [try this workaroound](https://askubuntu.com/q/1296048/349837) 
(also mentioned [on reddit](https://tinyurl.com/4fzwm23t) 
and a lot of other places; related to lie about touchpad size. Is a long standing annoying [GTK issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/1308) (followed by issue 3631), [fixed on KDE](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=403843).